# AWS VPC with a public and private subnet- instances can ping themselves but can't ping each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-vpc

I have a private subnet for the database server that has its own security group and a public subnet for the webserver with its own security group. both instances are in the same route table and ssh is inboud is enabled but still ping between the two instances is not reached

Comment: You should probably explain your security group for at least the private subnet.  Does it allow traffic from the public subnet for example?  Is ICMP traffic allowed?  i.e. need more detail

Comment: What do you mean by "both instances are in the same route table"? They are in different subnets, and those subnets should be using different route tables. Also, what is your "database server"? Is it just another Amazon EC2 instance, or are you using Amazon RDS? Also, _why_ do you want to enable ping? Are you trying to test connectivity between the web server and the database? You should test the actual connection (on the database port) rather than using Ping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable rules to allow ICMP in the security groups. Also verify your [network ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) allows ICMP.

Comment: inbound ICMP rules for 0.0.0.0/0 are enabled

Comment: Verify your network ACL also allows ICMP from public to private subnets.

Comment: I have enabled ICMP inbound traffic in the ACL as well